# Is there an XSD for XSD's, a Meta-XSD?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

Does there exist an Xml schema that will validate other XML schemas?

What I want to do is take such a meta-schema (if it exists) and run it through XSD.EXE so that I can use C# classes to read an arbitrary XML schema and analyze it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd

Answer (score 3):

For future references, I strongly discourage anyone to go down this path, when the intent is to validate and analyze an XML Schema.

.NET has a very robust API for doing this, in the [System.Xml.Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.aspx) namespace.